# What is wrong with this simple running JAVA class?

Tags: java

I don't know why I can't run compiled java class. Even very simple. Please see below.

```
C:\javatest>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin


C:\javatest>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

C:\javatest>cat hello.java
class hello{
public static void main(String[] agrs){
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
}
C:\javatest>javac hello.java

C:\javatest>java hello.class
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.class

C:\javatest>java -cp . hello.class
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.class

C:\javatest>
```

JAVA in windows path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin

Please help.

EDITED

```
C:\javatest>java hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello

C:\javatest>java.exe hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello
```

Comment: Why you are still working in command prompt.Havent you heard about eclipse?

Comment: Is version number is showing with `javac -version` and `java -version`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use command like:

```
C:\javatest>java hello  //Don't enter .class extension
```

Comment: Downvoter, please comment.

Comment: C:\javatest>java hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello

C:\javatest>java.exe hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin is enogh.  Remove the path  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin from Environmental variable

Comment: What I had to do is to run { java -cp . hello } thanks for Your help